# How can I change the "innodb_file_per_table" parameter from "OFF" to "1" for an existing database?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

When switching from MyISAM to InnoBD, I used the default settings. After reading the optimization tips, I realized that each table is better in a separate file. How to transfer the table from one file into a separate file each table mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using MariaDB 10.x, `innodb_file_per_table=1` is a default setting there, so as long as you are using defaults, your new InnoDB tables and those converted from MyISAM to InnoDB will already have separate tablespaces.

If you are using MariaDB 5.5, `innodb_file_per_table=0` by default. To start using individual tablespaces, run `SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table = 1;` . Since then and till server restart all newly created and altered InnoDB tables will use this option. To make the option permanent, add it to the cnf file.

To convert existing InnoDB tables into individual tablespaces, you can run
`ALTER TABLE <tablename> ENGINE=InnoDB` or `ALTER TABLE <tablename> FORCE`.

Answer (score 0):

More tips on conversion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

You *may* have to do this:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table = 1;
ALTER ...
```

I prefer to have big tables file_per_table, but small ones in ibdata1.

Comment: You actually don't need to re-connect for this. It is necessary for variables which have both GLOBAL and SESSION scope -- in this case SESSION variable is initialized upon connection, and changing the value for GLOBAL does not affect current session(s) -- you need to either re-connect or to set both SESSION and GLOBAL. Changes to variables which only have global scope normally take effect immediately (`innodb_file_per_table` is one of those). However, there are a few variables with rather obscure behavior, so when unsure, it's indeed easier to be safe.

Comment: @elenst - Thanks.  I've probably been burned by the inconsistencies.